# Cosmos DB RUs & Partitioning

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

*Apologies if this is a wrongly phrased question since this is my first post on stackoverflow*

Platform: **Cosmos DB**

Collection Configuration: **1000 RUs, Data Size < 10GB**

Data Configuration: **Partitioned Collection** (4 logical partition keys, each with a 1:2 growth ratio e.g. Key#1 holds 1 document then Key#2 contains TWO and so on)

**Question #1:**
If the underlying physical partitions are less than 10, does logical key distribution make any difference? *My understanding is that RUs are per physical partition.*

Spent some time reading [Partition and scale in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data) (thanks to [Azure Support Team](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) on Twitter). Information is elaborate, however, i'm in search of a simplified answer.

To rephrase the question, if the number of underlying physical partitions remain the same, if the overall collection size is under 10 Gb partition limit, does the distribution of logical partition key matter (considering that we end up querying the same physical partition)?

**Question #2:** 
In one of the Azure videos (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics) there was a hint that the CosmosDB Team was working on a possibility of having a configuration opportunity at key level. If released, does this feature address RU configuration at physical/ logical key level?

Comment: FYI, In my current scenario the portal mentions using only 1 physical partition that contains all 4 logical keys

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your question but... as your collections grow, logical partitioning becomes critical (e.g. you can never exceed 10GB within a logical partition). Also: if you created a partitioned collection, I don't think it's possible to only have one physical partition.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for your response. The 10GB limit is understood. No questions there. As for having just 1 physical partition, that's what is intriguing. The portal clearly says 1000 RUs distributed evenly over 1 physical partition. To confirm, I also verified the storage tab on the metrics blade. It just displays 1 partition bearing all (4) my logical partition keys.

Comment: To add to my comment earlier, this partitioned collection looks exactly the same as non partitioned one except for the fact that we have the opportunity to scale. Even the throughput metrics suggest a single partition with 1000 RUs

Comment: The comment from @DavidMakogon above is not accurate. Even if you create a partitioned collection it always starts with one physical partition and only goes into two and more as you start reaching the 10GB limit or more precisely 8GB size, when Cosmos DB proactively starts to split the data according to the partitioning key chosen to avoid going above 10GB. That may never happen if collection size remains small. So to answer your question - logical partitioning doesn't matter much in this case, but will once the collection grows beyond 8GB.

Comment: @alekseys agreed n understood